# Where are the RADIUS log events logged?

Tags: debian, login, logging

My server has a RADIUS functionality. I want to know where does it log about successful and rejected log-in events and other related info? I have to track RADIUS behavior so that's why it is important to know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged this as `debian`, i suppose it has `freeradius` installed.

The default configuration puts all logs in `/var/log/freeradius`. You can find successfull/failed login attemps in `/var/log/freeradius/radius.log`, and accounting information in `/var/log/freeradius/radacct/*`.

Comment: +1: Thanks for rapid answer. Follow up question: are there another RADIUS possibilities than freeradius? I still don't know which version that server has (no access yet) and would like to collect all the possibilities beforehand.

Comment: On debian, an `aptitude search radius` shows at least `radiusd-livingston`, `xtradius`, `yardradius` as *radius servers*. But nothing prevents you to compile one of the many others (try a search for radius server software on google). But chances are it really has FreeRADIUS installed (*The world's most popular RADIUS Server* as stated on the site).